# отличия фреймворка от MVC (PHP)

Tags: php, framework

А ведь по сути фреймворк, это тот же MVC, только написан очень круто?

Comment: MVC это набор ролей для компонентов программы, будь они в фреймворке или написаны лично вами. Не вполне понимаю, в чём суть вопроса.

Comment: Это вопрос из области сравнения `хрена с пальцем`.

Answer (score 1):

`MVC` это шаблон проектирования.

> Шаблон проектирования MVC предполагает разделение данных приложения, пользовательского интерфейса и управляющей логики на три отдельных компонента: Модель, Представление и Контроллер – таким образом, что модификация каждого компонента может осуществляться независимо.

Подробно о [MVC](https://habrahabr.ru/post/181772/).

Фреймворк это

> программная платформа, определяющая структуру программной системы; программное обеспечение, облегчающее разработку и объединение разных компонентов большого программного проекта.

Вот и подробно о [framework](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA).